# How to create an exception folder in a django site?

Tags: django, .htaccess, fastcgi, forum

There are a few folders where I house my django site that I want to be rendered as it would on any other non-django site. Namely, forum (vbulletin) and cpanel. I currently run the site with fastcgi. My .htaccess looks like this:

```
AddHandler application/x-httpd-php5 .htm
AddHandler application/x-httpd-php5 .html
AddHandler fastcgi-script .fcgi
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
AddHandler application/x-httpd-php5 .htm

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(mysite.fcgi)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ mysite.fcgi/$1 [QSA,L]
```

What are lines I can add so www.mysite.com/forum can not be picked up by django url and be rendered as it would do normally. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

in your apache vhost conf :

```
Alias /forum /home/django/project/forum
```

But i think its better to put your php stuff not inside your django project

Answer (score 0):

You can do

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(mysite.fcgi) [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^forum
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ mysite.fcgi/$1 [QSA,L]
```

This will ensure that the mysite.fcgi rule is triggered only if the url doesn't begin with forum.